# Extract URLs from a website based on position

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract URLs from a website (for example, [numpy](https://numpy.org/)); and then group it according to their positions, like header, body, sidebars, footer, etc.

I wrote my code below, and it is not working properly. It just picks the body and it is not even good:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to extract URLs from a webpage and group them by position
def extract_and_group_urls(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract all URLs from the webpage
    all_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
    
    # Group URLs based on their position (e.g., header, footer, body)
    url_groups = {
        'header_urls': [],
        'footer_urls': [],
        'body_urls': []
    }
    
    for url in all_urls:
        # Check if the URL contains certain keywords to determine its position
        if 'header' in url.lower():
            url_groups['header_urls'].append(url)
        elif 'footer' in url.lower():
            url_groups['footer_urls'].append(url)
        else:
            url_groups['body_urls'].append(url)
    
    return url_groups

# Example usage
url = 'https://numpy.org'  # Replace this with the URL of the website you want to scrape
url_groups = extract_and_group_urls(url)

# Print grouped URLs
print('Header URLs:', url_groups['header_urls'])
print('Footer URLs:', url_groups['footer_urls'])
print('Body URLs:', url_groups['body_urls'])
```

And my output:

```py
Header URLs: []
Footer URLs: []
Body URLs: ['/install', 'https://numpy.org/doc/stable', '/learn', '/community', '/about', '/news', '/contribute', '/pt/', '/ja/', '/', '/install', 'https://numpy.org/doc/stable', '/learn', '/community', '/about', '/news', '/contribute', '/pt/', '/ja/', '/news/#releases', '/news', '/news', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/LICENSE.txt', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy', '/community', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'http://qutip.org']
```

From the header it just picks /install, /learn. There were supposed to be proper URLs in the header file. I did the same for the footer.

Comment: It is rather unlikely that the information is directly in the URL, an orientation to the elements in which the links are located would probably be a somewhat better approach. for this, however, it would have to be clarified what is to be understood as `body`, since `header` and `footer` are usually elements within the `body`.

Comment: from the body i mean between header and footer

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it is rather unlikely that the information is directly in the URL, an orientation towards the elements in which the links are located would probably be a slightly better approach.

You could select elements that are "common" for header, footer - the following selctions with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) are only meant to hint at this and do not represent a full solution.

```
url_groups = {
    'header_urls': [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('header a[href], nav a[href]')],
    'footer_urls': [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('footer a[href]')],
    'body_urls': [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]:not(nav *,footer *)')]
}
```

You could combine this also with your approach looking for specifica in the url.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to extract URLs from a webpage and group them by position
def extract_and_group_urls(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    # Extract all URLs from the webpage
    all_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
    
    # Group URLs based on their position (e.g., header, footer, body)
    url_groups = {
        'header_urls': [a.get('href') if a.get('href').startswith('http') else 'https://numpy.org' + a.get('href') for a in soup.select('header a[href], nav a[href]')],
        'footer_urls': [a.get('href') if a.get('href').startswith('http') else 'https://numpy.org' + a.get('href') for a in soup.select('footer a[href]')],
        'body_urls': [a.get('href') if a.get('href').startswith('http') else 'https://numpy.org' + a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]:not(nav *,footer *)')]
    }
    
    return url_groups

# Example usage
url = 'https://numpy.org'  # Replace this with the URL of the website you want to scrape
url_groups = extract_and_group_urls(url)

# Print grouped URLs
print('Header URLs:', url_groups['header_urls'])
print('Footer URLs:', url_groups['footer_urls'])
print('Body URLs:', url_groups['body_urls'])
```

###### Output

```
Header URLs: ['https://numpy.org/install', 'https://numpy.org/doc/stable', 'https://numpy.org/learn', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org/about', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.org/contribute', 'https://numpy.org/pt/', 'https://numpy.org/ja/', 'https://numpy.org/', 'https://numpy.org/install', 'https://numpy.org/doc/stable', 'https://numpy.org/learn', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org/about', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.org/contribute', 'https://numpy.org/pt/', 'https://numpy.org/ja/', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCguIL9NZ7ybWK5WQ53qbHng', 'https://twitter.com/numpy_team']
Footer URLs: ['https://numpy.org/install', 'https://numpy.org/doc/stable', 'https://numpy.org/learn', 'https://numpy.org/citing-numpy', 'https://numpy.org/neps/roadmap.html', 'https://numpy.org/about', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org/user-surveys', 'https://numpy.org/contribute', 'https://numpy.org/code-of-conduct', 'https://numpy.org/gethelp', 'https://numpy.org/terms', 'https://numpy.org/privacy', 'https://numpy.org/press-kit', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCguIL9NZ7ybWK5WQ53qbHng', 'https://twitter.com/numpy_team']
Body URLs: ['https://numpy.org/news/#releases', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/LICENSE.txt', 'https://github.com/numpy/numpy', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'http://qutip.org', 'https://pandas.pydata.org', 'https://www.scipy.org', 'https://scikit-image.org', 'https://networkx.org', 'https://www.astropy.org', 'https://www.psychopy.org', 'https://pyquil-docs.rigetti.com/en/stable', 'https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels', 'https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io', 'https://opencv.org', 'https://graph-tool.skewed.de/', 'https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy', 'https://qiskit.org', 'https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/', 'https://python-control.org', 'https://mahotas.rtfd.io/', 'https://igraph.org/python/', 'https://github.com/spacepy/spacepy', 'https://pennylane.ai', 'https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn', 'https://pygsp.rtfd.io', 'https://biopython.org', 'https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/', 'https://www.scipy.org', 'https://cantera.org/', 'https://pangeo.io/', 'https://shapely.readthedocs.io', 'https://compas.dev/', 'http://scikit-bio.org', 'https://docs.pymc.io', 'https://www.sympy.org', 'https://www.mdanalysis.org/', 'https://simpeg.xyz/', 'https://geopandas.org/', 'https://cityenergyanalyst.com/', 'https://github.com/openvax/pyensembl', 'https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/', 'https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy', 'https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit', 'https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki', 'https://python-visualization.github.io/folium', 'https://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/', 'http://etetoolkit.org/', 'https://emcee.readthedocs.io/', 'https://fenicsproject.org/', 'https://www.pybamm.org', 'https://www.fatiando.org/', 'https://dask.org/', 'https://cupy.chainer.org', 'https://github.com/google/jax', 'https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html', 'https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/', 'https://pytorch.org/', 'https://www.tensorflow.org', 'https://mxnet.apache.org/', 'https://github.com/apache/arrow', 'https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python', 'https://awkward-array.org/', 'https://uarray.org/en/latest/', 'http://tensorly.org/stable/home.html', 'https://numpy.org/images/content_images/ds-landscape.png', 'https://pandas.pydata.org', 'https://intake.readthedocs.io', 'https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/', 'https://jupyter.org', 'https://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://matplotlib.org', 'https://altair-viz.github.io', 'https://scikit-learn.org', 'https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html', 'https://docs.pymc.io', 'https://spacy.io', 'https://plotly.com/dash', 'https://panel.holoviz.org', 'https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila', 'https://dask.org', 'https://ray.io/', 'https://dvc.org', 'https://mlflow.org', 'https://airflow.apache.org', 'https://dagster.io', 'https://www.prefect.io', 'https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/12/open-sourcing-embedding-projector-tool.html', 'https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/12/open-sourcing-embedding-projector-tool.html', 'https://scikit-learn.org', 'https://www.scipy.org', 'https://www.tensorflow.org', 'https://pytorch.org', 'https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet', 'https://towardsdatascience.com/ensemble-methods-bagging-boosting-and-stacking-c9214a10a205', 'https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost', 'https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/', 'https://catboost.ai', 'https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/', 'https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/', 'https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/best-python-data-visualization-libraries', 'https://github.com/yhat/ggpy', 'https://www.journaldev.com/19692/python-plotly-tutorial', 'https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/streamgraph.html', 'https://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://docs.pyvista.org/', 'https://napari.org', 'https://vispy.org/gallery/index.html', 'https://pyviz.org/overviews/index.html', 'https://matplotlib.org', 'https://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://plot.ly', 'https://altair-viz.github.io', 'https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/', 'https://holoviz.org', 'http://vispy.org', 'https://github.com/napari/napari', 'https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/blackhole-image', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/gw-discov', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/cricket-analytics', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/deeplabcut-dnn', 'https://numpy.org#']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't access header, body, footer tag. Instead,If the word 'header'/'body'/'footer' is present in the urls, then these urls will be appended to the header / body /footer_url list.

Since the urls belong to the same website, href attribute generally won't have the complete url. It will have only final path of the respective file.

Also the idea of accessing the urls based on html tag-name is not practical, because all the websites won't have standard structures of html elements. For example the numpy website doesn't have header tag at all.

So this is the code with explanation.

```
def extract_and_group_urls(url):
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    
    #considering nav tag as header and getting urls inside nav tags
    
    navtag = soup.body.find('nav').find_all('a')
    header_urls = [x.get('href') for x in navtag if x.get('href') != None]
    
    #adding main domain name in url if url doesn't contain main domain name

    header_urls = [url+x if url not in x else x for x in header_urls]
    
    #for body_urls - getting all urls except nav tag and footer tag
    
    ignore = ['nav', 'footer']
    for x in ignore:
        [y.extract() for y in soup(x)]
    
    body_tag = soup.find_all('a')
    body_urls = [x.get('href') for x in body_tag if x.get('href') != None]

    #adding main domain name in url if url doesn't contain main domain name
    
    body_urls = [url+x if url not in x else x for x in body_urls]

    #As the soup variable doesn't contain footer and header declaring soup again
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    #getting all urls of footer
    
    footer_tag = soup.find('footer').find_all('a')
    
    footer_urls = [x.get('href') for x in footer_tag if x.get('href') != None]

    #adding main domain name in url if url doesn't contain main domain name
    
    footer_urls = [url+x if url not in x else x for x in footer_urls]

    dct = {'header_urls' : header_urls, 'body_urls' : footer_urls, 'footer_urls' : body_urls }
    return dct
   
url = 'https://numpy.org' 
r = extract_and_group_urls(url)
print('header_urls= ', r['header_urls'])
print('body_urls= ',  r['body_urls'])
print('footer_urls= ', r['footer_urls'])
```

Output:

```
header_urls=  ['https://numpy.org/install', 'https:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.org/learn', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org/about', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.org/contribute', 'https://numpy.org/pt/', 'https://numpy.org/ja/']
body_urls=  ['https://numpy.org/install', 'https:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.org/learn', 'https://numpy.org/citing-numpy', 'https:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.org/about', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org/user-surveys', 'https://numpy.org/contribute', 'https://numpy.org/code-of-conduct', 'https://numpy.org/gethelp', 'https://numpy.org/terms', 'https://numpy.org/privacy', 'https://numpy.org/press-kit', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://twitter.com/numpy_team']
footer_urls=  ['https://numpy.org/news/#releases', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.org/news', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.org/community', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.org#', 'https://numpy.orghttp://qutip.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pandas.pydata.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.scipy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://scikit-image.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://networkx.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.astropy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.psychopy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pyquil-docs.rigetti.com/en/stable', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pywavelets.readthedocs.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://opencv.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://graph-tool.skewed.de/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://qiskit.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps://python-control.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://mahotas.rtfd.io/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://igraph.org/python/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pennylane.ai', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pygsp.rtfd.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://biopython.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.scipy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://cantera.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pangeo.io/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://shapely.readthedocs.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://compas.dev/', 'https://numpy.orghttp://scikit-bio.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://docs.pymc.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.sympy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.mdanalysis.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://simpeg.xyz/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://geopandas.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://cityenergyanalyst.com/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://python-visualization.github.io/folium', 'https://numpy.orghttps://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/', 'https://numpy.orghttp://etetoolkit.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://emcee.readthedocs.io/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://fenicsproject.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.pybamm.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.fatiando.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://dask.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://cupy.chainer.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pytorch.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.tensorflow.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://mxnet.apache.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python', 'https://numpy.orghttps://awkward-array.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttp:/../Playground/', 'https:/../Playground/-landscape.png', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pandas.pydata.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://intake.readthedocs.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://jupyter.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://matplotlib.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://altair-viz.github.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://scikit-learn.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://docs.pymc.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://spacy.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://plotly.com/dash', 'https://numpy.orghttps://panel.holoviz.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila', 'https://numpy.orghttps://dask.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://ray.io/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://dvc.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://mlflow.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://airflow.apache.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://dagster.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.prefect.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/-sourcing-embedding-projector-tool.html', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/-sourcing-embedding-projector-tool.html', 'https://numpy.orghttps://scikit-learn.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.scipy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.tensorflow.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://pytorch.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/-mxnet', 'https://numpy.orghttps://towardsdatascience.com/ensemble-methods-bagging-boosting-and-stacking-c9214a10a205', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps://catboost.ai', 'https://numpy.orghttps://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/-python-data-visualization-libraries', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/-plotly-tutorial', 'https://numpy.orghttps://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/streamgraph.html', 'https://numpy.orghttps://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://docs.pyvista.org/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://napari.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps://matplotlib.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://seaborn.pydata.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps://plot.ly', 'https://numpy.orghttps://altair-viz.github.io', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground//', 'https://numpy.orghttps://holoviz.org', 'https://numpy.orghttp://vispy.org', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.orghttps:/../Playground/', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/blackhole-image', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/gw-discov', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/cricket-analytics', 'https://numpy.org/case-studies/deeplabcut-dnn', 'https://numpy.org#']
```